# Apache running on Yosemite not working as expected

Tags: apache, url

I plan to use both `/Library/Webserver/Documents` and `~username/Sites/`. I have phpmyadmin folder in /Sites directory. If I go to

```
http://localhost/~username/phpmyadmin
```

it works, but if I go to

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

I get "The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.". I've reviewed the relevant files to make sure I enabled the relevant lines and such. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

You've essentially set up two different sites here:

For `http://localhost` your files are stored in `/Library/Webserver/Documents`.

For `http://localhost/~username` the files are stored in `~username/Sites`

Therefore, anything you put in `~username/Sites` will *only* be available when you go to `http://localhost/~username`.  If you want to keep the two things separate, you'll need to put the "phpmyadmin" under `/Library/Webserver/Documents` *instead of* `http://localhost/~username`.

Answer (score -1):

This question on Stack Overflow should be able to help get your localhost up and running again.

- [Get localhost running on OS X Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454160/get-localhost-running-on-mac-os-x-yosmite)

Comment: Well, I don't think this is exactly the answer. Its basically the same as the procedure that I was following wrt setting up Apache here: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.